# What is Hystrix in Spring?

Tags: spring, hystrix

Can someone please explain to me about Hystrix? I googled it, but still, I am not clear.

- What is Hystrix?
- Why do we use Hystrix?

Please provide me with an example of Hystrix usage.

Comment: Maybe this question is too general, but somehow exactly this is what I, this time as a visitor from google, wanted to know. I can't agree the downs.

Answer (score 56):

> What is hystrix?

Hystrix is a library developed by Netflix and is part of Spring via the [*Spring Cloud Netflix*](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/) project. Hystrix is a fault tolerance library and is used as strategy against failures (at different levels) in a service-layer.

> Why do we use Hystrix?

Hystrix can be used in situations where your application depends on remote services. In case one or more remote services are down you can handle the situation by using a [*circuit breaker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern) in your application.

> In simpler terms: How to allow one service to continue functioning – when it calls external services which are failing?

Hystrix is watching methods for failing calls to related services. If there is such a failing method, it will open the circuit, which means, it forwards the call to a fallback method. In case the services is restored it will close the circuit and the applications acts as expected again.

See this [great article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix) for more background.

Comment: The great irony of everyone telling OP to "just Google it" is that this question is now one of the top Hystrix google results :)

Comment: well said @Ataraxia I hate those sort of comments on SO. "Just google it" - I did, that's why I'm here...

Comment: checkout this blog, [link](https://technicalknowledgehub.com/netflix-hystrix/).

Answer (score 8):

> **What Is Hystrix?**

Hystrix is a latency and fault tolerance library designed to isolate points of access to remote systems, services and 3rd party libraries, stop cascading failure and enable resilience in complex distributed systems where failure is inevitable.

In a distributed environment, inevitably some of the many service dependencies will fail. Hystrix is a library that helps you control the interactions between these distributed services by adding latency tolerance and fault tolerance logic. Hystrix does this by isolating points of access between the services, 
stopping cascading failures across them, and providing fallback options, all of which improve your system’s overall resiliency.

> **What does it do?**

**1) Latency and Fault Tolerance**
Stop cascading failures. Fallbacks and graceful degradation. Fail fast and rapid recovery. Thread and semaphore isolation with circuit breakers.

**2) Realtime Operations**
Realtime monitoring and configuration changes. Watch service and property changes take effect immediately as they spread across a fleet.Be alerted, make decisions, affect change and see results in seconds.

**3) Concurrency**
Parallel execution. Concurrency aware request caching. Automated batching through request collapsing.

Some of the major implementations of hystrix are used in

> **Circuit Breaker**

This guide walks you through the process of applying circuit breakers to potentially-failing method calls using the Netflix Hystrix fault tolerance library.

> **Hystrix Dashboard**

The Hystrix Dashboard allows you to monitor Hystrix metrics in real time.

For further information on hystrix visit https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use

For further info regarding hystrix dashboard visit https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Dashboard

Comment: If someone feel that this is not useful answer, can you please comment on what went wrong with that answer. Suggestions are always welcomed.